How does this term in the Majorana mass not vanish?
This is classical field theory. In the Majorana mass term, we have the expression
$$\nu_L^T\sigma_2\nu_L \tag{1}$$
where the left-handed spinor field $\nu$ has a Grassmann-valued amplitude, i.e., $\nu = \mathcal{N} \text{(blah)}$ where $\mathcal{N}$ is a Grassmann number. How does $(1)$ not vanish? For, we can write $(1)$ as
$$\nu_L^T\sigma_2\nu_L = \mathcal{N}^2\text{(blah)}=0$$
by antisymmetry of $\mathcal{N}$ with itself.
Now, say that the above problem is resolved. Then, it seems like
$$\nu_L^T\sigma_2\nu_L = (\nu_L^T\sigma_2\nu_L)^T = \nu_L^T\sigma_2^T\nu_L = -\nu_L^T\sigma_2\nu_L,$$
which would again suggest that this expression does equal $0$. How does this expression not vanish given these two observations?

Grassmann-valued Transposition yields a minus sign, such as $(AB)^T=-B^T A^T$. See here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/388079/majorana-flip-relations?noredirect=1&la=2

Remember that $\nu_L$ is a two-component column vector with Grassmann entries $\nu_L^1$ and $\nu_L^2$, so with
$$
\sigma_2 =\left[\matrix{0&-i\cr i&0}\right],
$$
we have
$$
\nu_L^T \sigma_2 \nu_L = \left[\matrix{\nu_L^1, &\nu_L^2}\right] \left[\matrix{0&-i\cr i&0}\right] \left[\matrix{\nu_L^1 \cr \nu_L^2}\right]= -i(\nu_L^1\nu_L^2- \nu_L^2 \nu_L^1) =-2i\nu_L^1\nu_L^2\ne0.
$$

Oh, so we should not assume that it is merely the amplitude that is Grassmann-valued. It is, in general, the components themselves that are Grassmann-valued? Also, are Grassmann numbers affected by transpose? I.e., is $(\mathcal{N}_1 \mathcal{N}_2)^T = \mathcal{N}_2 \mathcal{N}_1$?

I'll edit to make clear.

I guess I mean to ask a slightly separate question about taking the tranpose $(\nu_L^T \sigma_2 \nu_L)^T$, which I keep finding to be antisymmetric. However, I know this term should not vanish and so should not be antisymmetric.

There is no meaning to $(\nu_L^T\sigma_2 \nu_L)^T$. How would you transpose a number? --- Grassman or not..... Now you can define an involution such that $(ab)^*=b^a^$, for Grassmanns, but that is not the same as a transpose, which is a matrix operation.

I mean that a number like $1$ would be left unchanged under transpose. But this allows us to rewrite the products we took to obtain this number, so that $(\nu_L^T \sigma_2 \nu_L)^T = \nu_L^T \sigma_2^T \nu_L$ per usual rules of matrix transpose. However, this gives the exact negative of the expression you wrote above and so would (incorrectly) suggest that this expression is zero.

Sorry, I have edited the original question add what I have been asking about in these comments and to clarify.

The matrix in  $(\nu^T\sigma \nu))$ has to be skew symmetric, and transposition interchanges the vectors being transposed, so both the interchange and the transpose gives a minus sign, making  the overall sign  unchanged.
